# Best way to convert object to integer

Tags: vb.net

I wish to safely convert an **object** from an external cache to an Integer type.

The only way I can seem to do this is inside a try catch block like so:

```
Try
    Return Convert.ToInt32(obj)
Catch
    'do nothing
End Try
```

I hate writing catch statements like this.

Is there a better way?

I have tried:

```
TryCast(Object, Int32)
```

Doesn't work (must be reference type)

```
Int32.TryParse(Object, result)
```

Doesn't work (must be a string type)

**UPDATE**

I like the comment posted by Jodrell - this would make my code look like this:

```
Dim cacheObject As Object = GlobalCache.Item(key)
If Not IsNothing(cacheObject) Then

    If TypeOf cacheObject Is Int32 Then
        Return Convert.ToInt32(cacheObject)
    End If

End If

'Otherwise get fresh data from DB:
Return GetDataFromDB
```

Comment: Where does this object comes from, and what's in it?

Comment: It comes from an external cache and it contains an integer. I can't trust it wont be malformed blob of data.

Comment: What do you think happens in `TryCast`?

Comment: An integer in string form? Or just a boxed `int`?

Comment: If it contains integers, cast it: `Return DirectCast(obj, Int32)`. You might want to use a `Try/Catch` just to ensure that the input is always valid, otherwise log the exception or show it to the user.

Comment: DirectCast will throw an exception

Comment: `If TypeOf obj Is Integer Then`

Comment: Jodrell - please post as answer

Comment: @geo1701 I've edited my existing answer

Comment: Your Convert.ToInt32(cacheObject) works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unesscessary conversion to `String` should be avoided.

You could use `Is` to check the type beforehand

```
Dim value As Integer
If TypeOf obj Is Integer Then
    value = DirectCast(obj, Integer)
Else
    ' You have a problem
End If
```

---

or,

You could implement a variation on `TryCast` like this,

```
Function BetterTryCast(Of T)(ByVal o As Object, ByRef result As T) As Boolean
    Try
        result = DirectCast(o, T)
        Return True
    Catch
        result = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Which you could use like this

```
Dim value As Integer
If BetterTryCast(obj, value) Then
    // It worked, the value is in value.
End If
```

Comment: I like you type checking (TypeOf obj Is Integer) idea - therefore I am awarding you the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Clarification: the question was originally tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net); the following applies **to C# only** (although may be translated into VB.NET):

---

If it is a boxed `int`, then:

```
object o = 1, s = "not an int";
int? i = o as int?; // 1, as a Nullable<int>
int? j = s as int?; // null
```

so generalising:

```
object o = ...
int? i = o as int?;
if(i == null) {
   // logic for not-an-int
} else {
   // logic for is-an-int, via i.Value
}
```

Comment: @Jodrell the tags originally added by the OP included C# - so I assumed C# was acceptable http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16582146/revisions

Comment: While the c# `as` is roughly equivalent to the VB `TryCast`, `TryCast` does not work with `Nullable<T>` because it is a value type (annoying limitation).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one is

```
Int32.TryParse(anObject.ToString, result)
```

Every Object has a ToString method and calling Int32.TryParse will avoid a costly (in terms of perfomance) exception if you Object is not a numeric integer. Also the value for result, if the object is not a string will be zero.

**EDIT**. The answer from Marc Gravell raised my curiosity. Its answer seems complex for a simple conversion, but it is better? So I have tried to look at the IL code produced by its answer

```
 object o = 1, s = "not an int";
 int? i = o as int?; // 1, as a Nullable<int>
 int? j = s as int?; // null
```

IL CODE

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  box         System.Int32
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // o
IL_0007:  ldstr       "not an int"
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // s
```

while the IL CODE produced by my answer is the following

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  box         System.Int32
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // anObject
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // anObject
IL_0008:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_000D:  ldloca.s    01 // result
IL_000F:  call        System.Int32.TryParse
```

Definitively the answer from Marc is the best approach. Thanks Marc to let me discover something new.

Comment: exceptions aren't actually all that expensive if you're not in an IDE

Comment: I dont like the idea of converting to a string

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
Int32.TryParse(a.ToString(), out b);
```